# Vim does not correctly draw screen when scrolling

Tags: vim, powershell, conemu

When running vim on Windows from Powershell through ConEmu and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to scroll in vim the screen only draws part of the file.

Normal:

[image]

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>:

[image]

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to force a redraw the screen then renders correctly again:

Is there a fix to cause the screen to always draw everything when using these commands?

EDIT: Setting the 'scroll' option to 9 or less appears to fix the problem as well, but this is not ideal and doesn't solve the root problem.

EDIT2: Setting the 'tsl' option to equal 0 instead of the default 999 gives desired behavior, but I still would like to know why this solved the problem.

Comment: What version of Vim? Is it up to date?

Comment: @Heptite I have updated to version 8 but I was still experiencing the same issue with 7.4.

Comment: same here and set tsl option solved it

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of the `TERM` environment variable, Vim's terminal behaviour is set by this.

`env | grep TERM`

Ensure it is set to `cygwin` in order for vim to work correctly with ConEmu.

NB This also applies in Bash, where I had a similar redraw errors when TERM was incorrectly set to `xterm`.